# Minimizing route distance with intersection routes with route constraint

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I've been trying to figure out the right class of algorithms that would apply to a route minimization problem that I have. Suppose I am flying an airplane, and I have to fly along the route, which are the black lines in the map. I can start anywhere, I can end anywhere, but all of the black area has to be flown.

[image: Airplane Flight Map]

What is a suitable algorithm that can minimizing the overall distance flown?

I want to enforce the constraint that each segment of black line is flown at least once. I've looked into Shortest Path and Traveling Salesman algorithms, and I haven't figured out how to add this final constraint in.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you represent each segment of black lines with non-negative integer variable $b_i$ with $i$ as index, then 
$1 \le  b_i \quad \forall i$: basically number of times rout $i$ is used.

You can tighten it further by, say nodes $ u,v$ form the a segment $i$ with
$ y_v + y_u - 1 \le b_i \le M(y_v+y_u)$ where binary $y$ indicates if node has been visited at least once & $M$ could upper bound of number of times a route can be possibly used.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Chinese postman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_postman_problem).  You can solve it with a combination of shortest paths and matching, as illustrated [here](https://communities.sas.com/t5/Mathematical-Optimization/Optimization-Visiting-all-arcs-in-a-network/td-p/867596).